# Program breaks in c# on process class

Tags: c#, process

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                info.FileName = "WK01.exe";
                info.Arguments = "WK01.exe";
                info.Arguments = fileName;
                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();


            }
        }
```

When I run this code , this code break on `p.Start();` , as my WK01.exe project contain 2 arguments , one is its path and second is what I give to it like picture or anything , when I run it and press the button it ask me for picking the file when I pick the file it break program on `p.Start();`

Comment: Why cmd.exe would be needed there at all?

Comment: And speaking of "breaks"... What is actually the exception which occurs?

Comment: Why cmd.exe ? WK01 is my project of c++ , and its getting command line argument , first argument is obviously its path and second is my input

Comment: @Agat I give me the option of Break , when i give the image as argument and cursor go on straight `p.Start();`

Comment: Hm... do you know what exceptions are? When the debugging locates you to the line with code, there must be also some exception message provided.

Comment: check whether your project file WK01.exe is there in the deployment folder(Debug or Relase) or not.

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified` along with the option of Break and Continue

Comment: @Sudhakar Yes it is there

Comment: Well, the exception describes the situation greatly: there is no wk01.exe file in folder of your project (bin/debug or bin/release (in this very case)).

Comment: @Ahmad "Project"? I don't understand you.

Comment: @Agat But WK01 is using many trained `XML` files , do i need to add them too in project refrences ? i didnt add that and project mean my `WK01.exe`

Comment: @Ahmad That's even not getting to the xml files. It says that "wk01" can not be found.

Comment: Please follow Crud answer below. if still you could not run then you try to run it from X86 Platform. right click on project -> properties->Build->change your platform Target from anycpu to X86, then build and run the project.

Comment: @Agat Your comments help me , actually my .exe was not in bin/debug , i was adding it only in debug. Answer me so i can mark it as correct , and let me update my problem relating to this in new thread

Comment: `Process` class implements `IDisposable` (via `Component`), so you need to wrap its lifetime in a `using` block for proper deterministic disposal of unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no wk01.exe executable file in your **bin/debug (or bin/release)** folder.

*If you want, you can add it to your project files (even as a reference) and mark as "Copy to Output directory = Copy always" to do that automatically.*

Answer (score 1):

`info.Arguments` you have updated twice.So its only take the last updated value.if you want to pass 2 argument you can do it as follows.

```
info.Arguments = "WK01.exe "+fileName;
```

Example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Crud My code only works if i add the image in my refrence in debug folder as well if i select the image from any other folder it give me the error of abort retry or ignore