# how to use passing arguments in command line

Tags: c#, json, command-line-arguments

I want to use my passing arguments in command line.My program is to generate latex file, from a lot of latex files using check boxes. And later to generate configuration files in which I save and load my chosen files, this configuration file is made by JSON format. After that I am making a Event load handler to keep my chosen check boxes checked as written in JSON file. So another step I want to make is using command line use my porgram.exe and my file.json, then my program.exe should keep check boxes checked as written in JSON format( It is working when running program, but I want to work it in command line, for example `cd c:\dir\program.exe file.json` ). How should I use those passing arguments in command line? here is my Load event handler code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cmdArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            if (cmdArgs.Length==1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("None file loaded as parameter");
            }
            if (cmdArgs.Length==2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("JSON file is not loaded as parameter");
                var dconfFilename = cmdArgs[1];
                LoadConfig(dconfFilename);
            }
        }
```

I found hard times to making it work in command lines. So I am asking your help or offers, how should I make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what exactly is wrong with this code. Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it produce unexpected results? If one of first tow, post the error message. If the issue is unexpected results, post both expected and current result. A config file you are trying to load and the command line command you are using are required too. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to another process in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ Андрей Беньковский as I said, everything runs and there is no compiling errors. If I run my program, everything is checked as written in JSON file. But i want to do it without compiling in my visual studio project. I want to run it in a command line( It should work like `cd c:/dir/program.exe file.json`) . I hope it is little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please describe the error messages or results you get on command line.
What should the command   `cd c:\dir\program.exe file.json`   do?
The command `cd` is for changing directory to the entered path in argument. You should try to call `c:\dir\program.exe file.json`, isn't it?

```
c:
cd c:\dir\
program.exe file.json
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I am doing. When I do this it runs program.exe. It opens my form window, but check boxes aren't checked as written in file.json. I want to make it checked.

Comment: I found my mistake, I just wasn't using my last version of program.exe . :)