# Run Console application by providing one argument using web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I have a console application called DocToPDF.exe on the desktop. I need to run it on the button click of a web application.I figured out how to run the application. The question is, the console application takes one argument.I need to figure out the way to pass the argument.The argument to be passed is "3750" Here is my code

```
   System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\itadmin\Desktop\DocToPDF\DocToPDF\DocToPDF\bin\Debug";

    process.StartInfo.Arguments= "/c \"" + "DocToPDF.exe" + "\"";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.Start();
```

And this is my console application that accepts the parameter using Console.Readline

```
  Console.Write("Enter Merchant Acct # : ");
  string strApprId = Console.ReadLine();
  strApprId = strApprId.Trim();
  Console.WriteLine("Something awesome is being processed......... ");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to another process in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why are you starting `cmd` and passing `DocToPDF.exe`? Can you not start `DocToPDF.exe` directly? And then pass it arguments?

Comment: Use space after your .exe and then pass your argument. `process.StartInfo.Arguments= "/c \"" + "DocToPDF.exe" + "\"" + " 3750";`

Comment: I tried passing directly DocToPDF.exe,but it does not take the argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pr=new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = "Specify arguments here";             
pr.StartInfo.FileName="Specify.exe file complete path here";
pr.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you works perfectly fine. Is there a way to not show the console window and run it in the background.