# How to start .exe and press enter with cmd or c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to run a .exe file which requires user input (press enter) to do further action. I want to call this .exe file for automation, as during automation argument enter need to be passed without user intervention, any idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: Just for clarification. You have prog_1 where you want to call prog_2 and pass parameters to it to mimic a user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp) may be it helps

Comment: what type of exe is it, c#? if so use IlSpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo. | programm.exe`
the dot after `echo` is required if you don't print anything else.

Comment: Not bad, but I think OP wants a `c#` solution?

Comment: thank you its kind of solved my problem ..