# Get string array from another application

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

The code which opens my app. and sends the arguments to my application:

```
 Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Laca\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\\bin\\Debug\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT.exe", "test");
```

I tried to process it:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    //public string[] ict_barcodes { get; set; }
    class ParamHolder
    {
        public static string[] Params { get; set; }
    }
    public MainForm(string[] ict_barcodes)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParamHolder.Params = ict_barcodes;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ParamHolder.Params[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
}
```

But it didn't work. I get the following error:

> Application.Run(new MainForm());
>   ->>Error  1   'SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT.MainForm' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments C:\Users\Laca\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\Program.cs  18  29  SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT

Any idea?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what do you want. Please specify your problem. Where do you create the `MainForm `?

Comment: So another program open my program, and sending to my program a string and i have to process it thats it but it doesn't work

Comment: And where is that code?  See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Comment: Here is the code:  Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Laca\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT\\bin\\Debug\\SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT.exe", "test");

And i have to process the test string in another application

Comment: I edited the question so can u help me or not? It's very important and i will be very grateful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to another process in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Main` method of **SMT_Previous_StationsChecker_Before_ICT** application you have to add input parameter like:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
```

and then in that method pass this parameter into `MainForm` constructor

```
Application.Run(new MainForm (args));
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help