# Passing command line arguments to the process that will be launched

Tags: c#, cmd, process, command, prompt

I am launching cmd.exe as administrator. I want to execute a CMD command ("**`lodctr /R`**") that will rebuild performance counter.

```
// run cmd to build perfomance counter
        string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        Process proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = 
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

How exactly can I execute this `cmd` command programmatically? And how does `StartInfo.Argumments` work???

[This picture explain how ("**`lodctr /R`**") rebuild performance counter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7ml.jpg)

Comment: Why are you running `cmd.exe` rather than `lodctr`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to another process in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Because i want to execute ("**`lodctr /R`**") in 'cmd.exe'

Comment: Why **specifically** do you want `cmd.exe` to be involved? Did you read the link I suggested?

Comment: I cannot find the answer in the link you suggested. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7ml.jpg This is what i want to produce with the code actually.

Comment: Did you try using `Arguments` (i.e set it to `"/R"`) as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057182/34092? And changing `path` to point to `lodctr` instead?

Comment: Can you please teach me how to use the Arguments ? Because after i read the link shown, still i cant understand. Thank you