# Exit child process without loosing data

Tags: c#, winforms

I had developed 2 C# WinForms application (2 different projects compiling to 2 different exes, App2 isn't having any UI, its simply having an icon in **notification tray**).

**App1** keeps working and at sometime when needed creates **App2** using following code,

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(applicationName);
Process.Start(info);
```

In App2's **main** function, I simply use `Application.Run(form1);`

Now, Sometime later I wish to ask that new process i.e. App2 to save all data and exit properly, how can I achieve this? I tried using,

```
Process.CloseMainWindow();
```

but it doesn't seems to work, because ***App2*** don't have any **User interface**. Decisions when to start and end App2 are taken in App1 itself.

Note: I don't wanna use `Process.Kill()` though it works, but it closes application abruptly.

Comment: What kind of data do you need saved?

Comment: Its kind of user activity logs which I need to save to local db, when user asks App1 to monitor logs, App2 needs to be started and record logs and when commanded from App2 it should exit.

Comment: Pass parameters while running app2 with Process.Start(info); and check these parameters in Main method of app2, decide what to do based on parameters. Everytime you call Process.Start(info), it invokes Main method of app2. see how to pass parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Munawar Yes I agree, every time I call Process.Start(info) it invokes main method, but I don't call it, if App2 is already running, and I need to ask App2 to exit from App1 itself, so what parameter should I pass on?

Comment: If app2 is already running then you need to bypass code which starts application e.g Application.Run(form1); and only process the parameters and let main method without starting another instance of application.

Comment: Something like this: static bool IsRunning = false;
        Form1 f;
        private static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            if (!IsRunning)
            {
                f = new Form1();
                Application.Run(f); IsRunning=true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Process parameters
            }
        }