# Running an application using cmd with command line in C#

Tags: c#, winmerge

I am working on a project that needs the cmd will run the application.

with an automatic filling of the textbox of application.

Currently, I have seen this code, but this does not work.

It throws this exception - `StandardIn has not been redirected`

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";                  
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" + txtJOB.Text + txtKJOB.Text + "- minimize - noninteractive - noprefs - cfg Settings / DirViewExpandSubdirs = 1 - cfg ReportFiles / ReportType = 2 - cfg ReportFiles / IncludeFileCmpReport = 1 - r - u -or" + txtResultPath.Text);
process.Start();
```

If i use cmd and run this line

`"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" + txtJOB.Text + txtKJOB.Text + "- minimize - noninteractive - noprefs - cfg Settings / DirViewExpandSubdirs = 1 - cfg ReportFiles / ReportType = 2 - cfg ReportFiles / IncludeFileCmpReport = 1 - r - u -or" + txtResultPath.Text`

this does work. but how will i Implement this command line in c#?

can someone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @mjwills. Sir? This waas the only message shown on the console. `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
StandardIn has not been redirected.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception is thrown because you writing a command to standart input of process (`process.StandardInput.WriteLine()`) **before** you actually start process (`process.Start()`).

If you just need to start a `WinMergeU` - you don't need to call `cmd.exe` at all, this can be done like this:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe";
var arguments = $"{txtJOB.Text} {txtKJOB.Text} -minimize -noninteractive -noprefs " +
     "-cfg Settings/DirViewExpandSubdirs=1 -cfg ReportFiles/ReportType=2 " +
    $"-cfg ReportFiles/IncludeFileCmpReport=1 -r -u -or {txtResultPath.Text}";

Process.Start(fileName, arguments);
```

Comment: You just save me Sir. Thank you. God Bless!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Arguments` property on `ProcessStartInfo`

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" + txtJOB.Text + txtKJOB.Text + "- minimize - noninteractive - noprefs - cfg Settings / DirViewExpandSubdirs = 1 - cfg ReportFiles / ReportType = 2 - cfg ReportFiles / IncludeFileCmpReport = 1 - r - u -or" + txtResultPath.Text;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

```

Comment: Sir? This only shows up the cmd. and the WinMerge is not running. By the way, thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to add spaces between, before and after file names: ...WinMergeU.exe" + " " + txtJOB.Text + " " + txtKJOB.Text + " -...