# How to Provide parameters to a process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

Hi I'm trying to Create a Windows form app written in c# that will start ,Stop and monitor if it is running or not of a another Console application.

Now i able to start the Console app on my Windows App but How can i provide values to its  Console.ReadLine

Here's my code:

The windows App:

```
 int ProcessIDDaca = 111111111;
        private void btnDacaStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                using (Process myprocess = new Process())
                {
                    myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\MachineMonitor\CopyChimp_Server\bin\Debug\CopyChimpServer.exe";
                    //myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Eltima Software\Virtual Serial Port Driver 9.0\vspdconfig.exe";
                    myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    if (btnDacaStart.Text == "Stop")
                    {
                        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessIDDaca);
                        proc.Kill();
                        btnDacaStart.Text = "Start";
                        lblDacaID.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myprocess.Start();
                        var s = myprocess.Id;
                        ProcessIDDaca = myprocess.Id;
                        lblDacaID.Text = s.ToString();
                        btnDacaStart.Text = "Stop";
                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

Console App:

```
  public static string copychimp_server = "";
  public static int port_number = 0;

  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter copychimp server: ");
            //Here i need to provide
            copychimp_server = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter port number: ");
            //Here i need to provide
            port_number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());


        }
```

And Also why is not showing but i can see it is running on my task manager?
A help is highly appreciated for me like a beginner in programming.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

i already solve it 
My latest code:

```
int ProcessIDDaca = 111111111;
        private void btnDacaStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                using (Process myprocess = new Process())
                {
                    myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\MachineMonitor\CopyChimp_Server\bin\Debug\CopyChimpServer.exe";
                    //myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Eltima Software\Virtual Serial Port Driver 9.0\vspdconfig.exe";
                    myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    if (btnDacaStart.Text == "Stop")
                    {
                        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessIDDaca);
                        proc.Kill();
                        btnDacaStart.Text = "Start";
                        lblDacaID.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "test";
                        myprocess.Start();
                        var s = myprocess.Id;
                        ProcessIDDaca = myprocess.Id;
                        lblDacaID.Text = s.ToString();
                        btnDacaStart.Text = "Stop";
                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

public static string copychimp_server = "";
  public static int port_number = 0;

  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter copychimp server: ");
            //Here i need to provide
            copychimp_server = args[0];
            Console.Write("Enter port number: ");
            //Here i need to provide
            port_number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());


        }
```

Reference link
[How to pass parameters to another process in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Why have you set myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow by true? Set it to false and try again.

Comment: Now it is showing but how can i provide to the readline on the console?

Comment: Now this winodw is same with other console wins can't you enter it?